# What connects the strangeness of the people and the magic of the bathroom?

Tags: short-stories, character-analysis, turkish-language, sine-ergun

I was just reading [Turkish Short Stories](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/issue/october-2017-turkish-short-stories) from the October 2017 issue of [*Words Without Borders*](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/). In particular, the story ["The Little Bathroom"](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/october-2017-turkish-short-stories-the-little-bathroom-sine-ergun-ayca-turk) by Sine Ergün (published freely online, and translated into English by Ayça Türkoğlu, so you can read it in full at the linked page).

The story begins by introducing the flatmates Selen, Onur, and İnanç, who are all described as *strange* in one way or another. Later on we learn that the second, unused, bathroom in their flat is some kind of magical place, although exactly what kind of magic isn't really described in detail.

**What's the connection between the residents' 'strangeness' and the magic in the bathroom?**

I'd be interested in answers based on either an in-universe connection (did the magic make them strange? could only strange people live in such a flat?) or a thematic connection in the story (does reading about strange people prepare us for a magic bathroom?) or both. At the moment, their strangeness and the bathroom's magic seem to me like two unconnected phenomena, but I'm guessing there's something I haven't picked up on.